# AJAX Call before jsp:include in same jsp

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I need know to execute one **ajax function** before than one **jsp:include** puts in same jsp.

I try put one session parameter with this ajax function, this parameter is used for include, but first jsp execute include and parameter is not put and imposible to use.

Someone know fix my problem?, thanks guys!

Comment: You are mixing up server-side and client-side execution. jsp:include happens on the server when the response is generated. Any Javascript (AJAX is Javascript, remember) is executed by the browser on the client AFTER the response has been generated and sent back.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX and JSP are completely different technologies and are run on different systems and at different times.

JSP processors are executed when the page is generated, i.e. on the server side.
AJAX functions are triggered in the browser by Javascript (hence A**J**AX) which is available *after* the page has been generated (using JSP) and delivered.

If the AJAX function triggers a JSP on the server side, the JSP or Servlet should read the needed parameter from the request first (the AJAX call would put it there), e.g. by accessing the implicit `request` object in an expression within the `<jsp:include>` tag.